# Why findall() function return a weird value?

Tags: python, regex

```
>>>import re    
>>>re.findall(r"[^>]*", "<abc>")
['<abc', '', '']
```

When i type above code in Python interpreter, i got a weird result.

Why the length of returned list is 3 not 2 ?

Comment: `[^>]*` matches empty locations in front of non-matching chars because `*` matches **0** or more occurrences.

Comment: `[^>]+`  try this

Comment: I understand why '+' gives better results, but what empty locations are you referring too?   Adjusting the input string to varying lengths still yields an array of three, when I could possibly justify an array of two.      >>> re.findall(r"[^>]*", "<abcdsdfd")
['<abcdsdfd', '']
>>> re.findall(r"[^>]*", "<abcdsdfd>")
['<abcdsdfd', '', '']